# error 3 error Illegal characters found in URL Curl Php

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php 
//$searchterm = "acer predator 21x";
//$searchres =  urlencode($searchterm);
$reffer = "https://www.google.com/";
$LOGINURL = "https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=acer+predator+21x&oq=acer+predator+21x&gs_l=psy-ab.3...116308.122177.0.126746.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.jZC5TmHjRnI
";  

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0";

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);


    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  if(curl_error($ch)) {
        echo "error ".curl_errno($ch)."<br / >";
        echo "error ".curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $result;

 ?>
```

Am searching on google using php curl and am getting this error "error 3
error Illegal characters found in URL", what could be the problem i have tried to search on the stack and i cant find any helpful answer.

Comment: You have \n at the end of URL

Comment: check my answer, i have in this way u can remove extra space and \n from url

Answer (score 1):

Sure iXCray

```
$LOGINURL="https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=acer+predator+21x&oq=acer+predator+21x&gs_l=psy-ab.3...116308.122177.0.126746.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.jZC5TmHjRnI"; //no \n anymore
```

That works!!

Answer (score -1):

Dynamically replace \n and extra space from url, like this

```
<?php 
//$searchterm = "acer predator 21x";
//$searchres =  urlencode($searchterm);
$reffer = "https://www.google.com/";
$string = "https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=acer+predator+21x&oq=acer+predator+21x&gs_l=psy-ab.3...116308.122177.0.126746.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.jZC5TmHjRnI
";  
$LOGINURL = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0";

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);


    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  if(curl_error($ch)) {
        echo "error ".curl_errno($ch)."<br / >";
        echo "error ".curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $result;

 ?>
```

Comment: trim doesn't need preg_replace inside, moreover it already removes  "\t\n\r\0\x0B" additionally to spaces according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: trim replace "\t\n\r\0\x0B" from start and end of the string but not between/through out the script, trim needs preg_replace here.

Comment: Well, your solution doesn't do it either.

Comment: doesn't do either means? its giving me data

Comment: You replace many spaces with one space. Then you trim spaces from beginning and end. Space in between still exists. So, again: wtf is preg_replace? Yes, it is giving you data, because of trim. Not because of preg_replace.